# When I use tornado web server, logs show this error. How can I resolve it?

Tags: python, tornado

> [W 200709 09:47:12 iostream:887] Write error on <socket.*socketobject object at 0x36c2910>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [I 200709 09:47:12 web:2064] 200 GET /templates/js/system/sytemlog-control.js?*=1594259185262 (10.2.26.57) 8.45ms
> [I 200709 09:47:12 web:2064] 304 GET /templates/html/main.html?u=system/systemlog (10.12.33.99) 7.92ms
> [W 200709 09:47:13 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36c2ad0>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:13 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36c2c90>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:13 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36c2d00>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:14 iostream:887] Write error on <socket.*socketobject object at 0x36c2ec0>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [I 200709 09:47:14 web:2064] 200 GET /templates/js/system/sytemlog-control.js?*=1594259245749 (10.12.33.99) 1.74ms
> [W 200709 09:47:15 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36c2fa0>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:16 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x3610f30>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:17 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36108a0>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [I 200709 09:47:18 web:2064] 200 POST /auth/system/log!list?callback=jQuery2140877480096841464_1594259245751 (10.12.33.99) 242.50ms
> [W 200709 09:47:18 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x3610050>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:19 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x3610210>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:20 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x3610130>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:21 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x3610c90>: [Errno 113] No route to host
> [W 200709 09:47:22 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36103d0>: [Errno 113] No route to host

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it is quite simply that the ability for the Tornado server to connect via this socket has been lost.

This assumes there was a connection open between the Tornado server and something else (by the context of what you said): has the network been changed? Have you shut a dependency down that the Tornado server relies on!?! Has a shared socket based filesystem disappeared???

I hope this helps, but basically somewhere in your Tornado servers world a connection has been broken.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thx Jim, It can be seen from the log that this error occurs randomly,I pasted some other information,can you have a look? Thx again!

Comment: Hi Li
All I can see is that `[W 200709 09:47:13 iostream:887] Write error on <socket._socketobject object at 0x36c2c90>: [Errno 113] No route to host` continues amongst successful requests. It appears there is something at the OS level affecting operation, but that's not really any more information than we gathered before. Can you think of anything that might be responsible for underlying OS instability: running off network drives / removable disks etc etc...?

Comment: Okey, I'll see it,Thx very much Jim!